# Тире как заменитель "это"

Tags: пунктуация

Со школьной скамьи мы знаем, что тире часто ставится перед "это", либо заменяет его. Например, "Пушкин - классик русской литературы" (а можно было бы написать: "Пушкин - это классик русской литературы"). Но такое наблюдается не всегда.
Например, такое предложение: "Я все еще не мог поверить, что все происходящее не розыгрыш". Тут тире поставлено не было. Так когда в случае пропущенного "это" нужно ставить тире, а когда нет?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тире между подлежащим и составным именным сказуемым   не ставится, если подлежащее выражено личным местоимением,

если перед сказуемым-существительным есть сравнительные союзы  как,  словно, будто,точно и др.,

вводное слово,

частица НЕ,

другие частицы(ведь, только, именно);

если есть наречие,союз,несогл.втор.член.;

если сказ. предшествует подлежащему: Какое удовольствие бродить в лесу!

В Вашем примере есть частица НЕ, поэтому нет тире.

Но если очень хочется выделить сказуемое паузой, допускается авторское тире, например, у Маяковского: Я- гражданин Советского Союза тире авторское, оно придаёт значительность сказуемому.

Comment: Только тире здесь заменитель не  "это", а связки "есть"( был, будет), а это можно подставить, а можно и без него

Comment: А вот в моём примере есть "не", и есть тире:

>Всё происходящее - это не розыгрыш.

Comment: Но ведь "не" стоит после "это"

Comment: У Людмилы про _это_ в ответе ничего не сказано.

Comment: В правилах - тоже ничего не сказано. Тире ставится перед " это", независимо от того, что стоит после этого.

Comment: О том и речь. Людмила вводит читателей в заблуждение, сообщая, что "_тире не ставится, если перед сказуемым-существительным есть частица НЕ_". Я привёл контрпример.

Comment: Вы ко мне, видимо, неравнодушны, что цепляетесь к словам и называете заблуждением, если не оговорены ВСЕ причины непостановки тире. Видимо, должно быть так:"Тире между подлежащим и составным именным сказуемым не ставится, если ... перед сказуемым-существительным есть сравнительные союзы ,частица НЕ (если перед ней нет ЭТО)..." Просто я думала, что это само собой разумеется и автор вопроса это знает.Зачем расписывать всё для грамотных людей? В ответах на Ваши вопросы постараюсь отвечать более полно, всё разжёвывая.

Answer (score 1):

"Это" - слово-связка между подлежащим и именной частью сказуемого, в этом случае делается  пауза и ВСЕГДА ставится тире. (Предложение со словом-связкой является особой грамматической конструкцией, нельзя сказать, что "это" заменяет тире).

Связка не является обязательным элементом, при отсутствии связки постановка тире зависит от того, чем выражено подлежащее и сказуемое (тире обычно ставится, если главными членами является инфинитив или существительное и не ставится, если именной частью сказуемого является прилагательное, наречие). Назначение тире - ОТДЕЛИТЬ состав подлежащего от состава сказуемого в тех случаях, когда в этом есть необходимость, то есть когда их трудно различить.

Если между подлежащим и сказуемым находится частица(НЕ, только), союз КАК, наречие, вводное слово, то пауза не делается и тире не ставится. В этом случае "разделителями" являются эти слова.

Однако все эти правила имеют исключения или постановка тире может быть авторской. И только при наличии связки ЭТО тире ставится всегда.

Answer (score 0):

Тире не ставится, если перед сказуемым стоит отрицание ***не***: Сердце не камень (Погов.); Аналогия не доказательство. 
Постановка тире в этом случае имеет целью логически и интонационно подчеркнуть сказуемое: Но объяснение - не оправдание (М. Г). Д.Э. Розенталь. Русский язык. Справочник- Практикум. Стр. 129.

Comment: А если автор захочет тут поставить смысловое тире? Скажем, подчеркнуть особо, что сердце - не камень (вот, как сейчас, например)?

Comment: Да, такое тире допустимо.